# JSON/PHP not parsing correctly

Tags: php, javascript, json

Firstly i'll point out the problem, basically inside my `$.each(data, function (i, v) {` code it's returning a bunch of variables which are echo'd from the **PHP** code which is using `json_encode` but when trying to place these variables or even `alert()` them it's showing `undefined` i've tried many ways to actually display the data, but it's always returning `undefined` and i don't know why since my code seems valid to my perspective.

The current **javascript** code i have is as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url: "functions/ajax.php",
        data: "func=auto",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            var name = v['name'];
                            var player_id = v['id'];
                            alert(player_id);
                });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
        }
});
```

The current **PHP** code i have is as follows

```
$res = $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `account_id` = '$_SESSION[ID]'");
$data = array();
while($player = $DB->fetch_assoc()) {   
        $data['name'] = $player['name'];
        $data['id'] = $player['player_id'];
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Just to sum the whole thing up, when using `alert()` on `player_id` it returns `undefined` in which obviously i want it to return the correct value

Comment: There is only one player in there, so don't `.each()` over it. Or run `$data[] = array('name'=>$player['name'],'id'=>$player['player_id']);`

Comment: Would that work because my `while($player = $DB->fetch_assoc()) {` is returning more than one result ?

Comment: Look at what `$data` is in your current script. It will only be last player in the list unless you append records to `$data` instead of _overwriting_ it.

Comment: Ah, well, @MarcB took the time to explain it more in depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not sending back a multi-level array, you're sending an array with just two elements. e.g. your JS code should be

```
    success: function(data){
               var name = data['name'];
               var player_id = data['id'];
             }
```

If that DB query **IS** supposed to send back multiple records, then you're building it wrong:

```
while($player = $DB->fetch_assoc()) {   
   $data[] = array('name' => $player['name'], 'id' => $player['player_id']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

and then your `$.each()` code should start working, as you ARE sending back a multidimensional array/object.